# WPF StackPanel add item and other item stays the same place

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I need to make a titlebar to a stackpanel. I need to add it and make the stackpanel's other content stay in the same place. So I should move the stackpanel a little down to make the titlebar look like it just appeared above it. However this doesnt work with rotation.

This is the code I tried which doesnt seem to work with rotation:

```
Panel.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(delegate(object o, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Point p = new Point(0, -15);
   Border.RenderTransform.Transform(p);
   Canvas.SetTop(Border, WindowManager.NaNToZero(Canvas.GetTop(Border)) + p.Y);
   Canvas.SetLeft(Border, WindowManager.NaNToZero(Canvas.GetLeft(Border)) + p.X);
   Panel.Children.Insert(0, TitleBorder);
});
Panel.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(delegate(object o, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Point p = new Point(0, 15);
   Border.RenderTransform.Transform(p);
   Canvas.SetTop(Border, WindowManager.NaNToZero(Canvas.GetTop(Border)) + p.Y);
   Canvas.SetLeft(Border, WindowManager.NaNToZero(Canvas.GetLeft(Border)) + p.X);
   Panel.Children.Remove(TitleBorder);
});
```

I would really appreciate a solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would simply making the Title element Visible and Collapsed when you need it work for you?

Comment: I would like to make it invisible when not hovering over. If there's any other solution than placing it in the panel please let me know.

Comment: Invisible or Collapsed. If collapsed, completely disappears, you can't hover over it. If invisible, why? If you want the Title to display when you hover over the Panel it seems you can just adjust the Visibility of Title.